# What is the music playing in reverse on the Whimsyshire level?

Tags: diablo-iii, game-music-identification

I've noticed that the music in the Whimsyshire level appears to be playing in reverse.

Can anyone confirm this? If so, is it music from another level or a famous piece or a unique song being played in reverse?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's a section in the [Diablo Wiki](http://www.diablowiki.net/Whimsyshire#Whimsyshire.27s_Music) (includes videos) about that:

> The music played in the level is a famous piece of classical music for the piano, Ravel's Gaspard de la Nuit - Le Gibet.